# How do I restore the previous RecyclerView state when a fragment is recreated?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `Fragment` in my Android app that has a `RecyclerView` and I want to restore the `RecyclerView` it previously had from the last time the user opened the app.

In my `Fragment` I have the following blocks of code for saving and restoring the `RecyclerView`.

```
private val LIST_STATE_KEY = "recycler_state"
private var recyclerViewState : Parcelable? = null
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY, recyclerView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState())
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        recyclerViewState = savedInstanceState?.getParcelable(LIST_STATE_KEY)
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (recyclerViewState != null) {
        recyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

The problem I have now is when I open the app for the first time, I populate the `RecyclerView`, close the app, open it again and when I go to that specific fragment, the `RecyclerView` is empty. What am I doing wrong here? Why is my app not saving the `RecyclerView` data it previously had before the app closed and restoring the data it saved onto the `RecyclerView` when the app opens again?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is used for saving data when configuration is changing, such as rotating device. When you close the app and launch it again this data is lost. You may need to use other methods of saving data like `SharedPreferences` or `DataBase` for your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farid correctly says in the comment: These methods are used in cases when the Activity is destroyed, for example, when there is a lack of memory or when the configuration is changed (screen rotation and others). If you just clicked the Back button and thereby explicitly closed the Activity yourself, then these methods will not be executed.

If you want to have data after closing the application, then you must save this data to persistent memory.
The [Preference Library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/use-saved-values) is suitable for storing the simplest variables.
If the data structure is complex, then it is better to use [Database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).

Comment: For each `RecyclerView` item I have it stores three string values and one BigDecimal value. Would a database be necessary? I should also mention the data would be different for each user since you have to sign in to the app before being able to use the fragment.

Comment: @TomDarious If you really want to cache list data, then you can't do without a database. You will save this data the first time you retrieve items, so there will be no problem with everyone having different data.